# Prevent underscore templates from using global variables

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

My underscore template contains the following:

```
<% if (typeof title !== "undefined") { %>
    <p class="title"><%= title %></p>
<% } %>
```

Without name spacing my template data before rendering (`data.title`), is there a way to prevent underscore from using the global scope? I have to rely on `undefined` and cannot safely remove `title` from the global scope (not my code).

Comment: No, there is not. There's nothing wrong with namespacing your template (and using the `variable` option)

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, I realize there's nothing wrong with it. That will likely be the route I go. I just have a lot of existing code and was searching for a possible underscore setting or workaround. Looks like there isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no (thanks to Bergi for commenting). I'd been hoping to avoid having to update several dozen complicated underscore templates from `<%= foo %>` to `<%= data.foo %>`, but in the end, had to do it.

Answer (score 1):

cough cough  my patch, parses template for keys and creates placeholders

https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/237

or if your uncomfortable patching a core library, with random code from the internet :)

you can wrap the template in a try catch and have a error message

```
<% try { %>
    TEMPLATE OF DOOM FULL OF FAIL
<% } catch (error instanceof ReferenceError){ %> 
    GENERIC REFERENCE ERROR MESSAGE
<% } %>
```

or better yet pass in wrapped object, and reference the wrapped key

eg see how naked "dataIWasGoingToPutIntoTemplateUnwrapped" is wrapped in key "data"

```
var dataIWasGoingToPutIntoTemplateUnwrapped = {
     iAmVar:"hello",
     iHasVarKThxBye:"world"
};

var underscoreTemplate = _.("<%= data.iAmVar %> and <%=data.iHasVarKThxBye%>");
console.log(underscoreTemplate({data:dataIWasGoingToPutIntoTemplateUnwrapped }));
```